# How to get sudo access without reboot? (on remote server)

Tags: debian, sudo

(From remote Debian server)
When you give `sudo` right with `visudo` for the first time on first boot to a new user, `su - <newuser>` will not be enough to offer the right to use `sudo` and then reboot the server is the way to get the right to use the `sudo` command.

Then you get back:

```
[sudo] password for <newuser>: 
<newuser> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I have tried `service sudo restart` but that does not make the trick

```
:~$ getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:<newuser>
:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for <newuser>: 
<newuser> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Do you think there is an efficient way to do that?

Information on configuration: Debian wheezy

`EDITOR=vim visudo`

uncommented: `sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

`gpasswd -a <newuser> sudo`

Comment: I've never had to reboot to add sudo privileges. Perhaps you have a typo for "sudo ALL..." where it should be "%sudo ALL ..." ?

Comment: I always need to reboot. @JeffSchaller

Comment: @aurelien, in that case there is something wrong with your system. `sudo` should never need rebooting after installation

Comment: It is a fresh installed system, and first thing I have do is to create the sudo. And for the moment I have not restarted it to try to understand that trouble @MelBurslan

Comment: @JeffSchaller had it.  `%sudo` does not comment out the line, it specifies that you're looking for the group `sudo`.  Without the `%`, it's instead looking for a user named `sudo` which doesn't exist.  No idea why a reboot would change that though.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just:

```
# echo "<newuser>  ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Cf: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch01.en.html#_sudo_configuration

And personnaly I would use:

```
# tee -a "<newuser>  ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

`tee -a` present the advantage of merge stuff to the existant without removing the old stuff

Comment: That does solve the issue, but it only applies `sudo` privileges to the specific user.  For a system with only a few users this would be okay, but in an environment where there may be a larger number of administrators and they change periodically it becomes a bit harder to manage.

Comment: There is no way to log out remote server. Exit just cut the ssh connection, it does not offer you a way to login. This is only possible on a Virtual Machine!

Comment: About the point of larger number of administrators: Well, the situation is about a newly installed remote server where you login for the first time and install sudo.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to reboot, but you do need to log out and back in which a reboot forces you to do.  Your group membership isn't dynamically updated, so if you add yourself to the `sudo` group you won't be a member of the group until the next time you log in.

Comment: How do you log out from remote terminal? exit does not make the trick

Comment: With the system still running, disconnect from all sessions (if you're logged in via SSH, exit or logout).  Open a brand new shell as the user you want to use `sudo` as.  You can now examine your group membership using `id` and verify you're in the `sudo` group.  At this point, you should be able to use `sudo`.

Comment: bash: logout: not login shell: use `exit' so no and as always explain exit from remote does not logout but cut the connection. and about the id I have explain that 
:~$ getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:<newuser>
 so the newuser is already in the group, but nothing happen. So no that does not make the trick @mkomarinski

Comment: :~$ id
uid=1000(newuser) gid=1000(newuser) groups=1000(newuser),27(sudo) which give the same back as the getent

Comment: That's the core of your problem, you need to completely disconnect from the remote server and then log back in as the user.  Using `id` will tell you what your current group memberships are from the shell and will be more accurate than using `getent`

Comment: Try the following command `exec su -l $USER` and type sudo password

Comment: You are right about id VS getent but that does not solve the trouble @mkomarinski

Comment: @GAD3R nop ... that does not make the trick :~$ exec su -l $USER
Password: 
:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for <newuser>: 
<newuser> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: @aurelien you haven't logged off the remote server. Group membership is assigned at the time you log in, so until you have a fresh login you will not be able to use `sudo`.

Comment: @roaima that is wrong, as I say in the right response and test it on fresh remote servers. Some seems not pleased of that, but, that is for part a response from Debian itself! applause and give my points back!

Comment: @aurelien I'm pleased for you to have found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @roaima thanks, but it works for all fresh install. test it on a VM if you do not trust me.